# I want to increase the size of my boot partition (Ubuntu 14.04 version)

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I read in another post that kernels are distributed as new releases rather than upgrades. I didn't know this when I was allocating space to my partitions during my initial install of Ubuntu. As a result I ran out of space on my boot partition. Can I increase the size of it using GParted and how do I do this without doing damage to my system?

1      1049kB  512MB   511MB  fat32              boot
 2      512MB   768MB   256MB  ext2
 3      768MB   1000GB  999GB                     lvm

Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 3712MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  3712MB  3712MB  linux-swap(v1)

Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 996GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  996GB  996GB  ext4

Sorry, don't know how to capture and post the terminal output screen.

Comment: The more logical approach would be to remove olders kernels than the last working one, the current and the new one (so keep 3). Like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot or this http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu

Comment: Yes, I already did that. It is a very small partition though at 230 Mb.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo parted -l`